# How do I un-nominate a re-open vote?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-reopen

Recently, I nominated to re-open one of my question after adding some more details to the question. But after that I realized that the linked answer did have useful points to solve my problem. I tried to retract my vote/nomination to re-open my question, but didn't find any way to do so.

Is there any way to retract/un-nominate a re-open vote? (yea too many -ve -ve statements :))

Answer (score 2):

You can't retract a reopen vote, but like close votes they age away. So if no one else thinks your question should be reopened the vote will just disappear after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to retract a reopen vote.

If you think the question should be closed, you can check back on the question later and if it's reopened, vote to close it.

Comment: Why the 2 down votes? I was first to answer people!!! Look at the timestamps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retract a reopen vote, no.