# Add an ability to revert my vote to re-open the question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

I voted to re-open a question closed as duplicate [Json Datetime issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757757/json-datetime-issue), because two linked questions were about different language. Then I realised that the question is still a duplicate - of the third question.
I've edited the content, providing a correct link, but I am unable to revert my vote to re-open the question. When I click the 're-open' link, the message asks me "Nominate the question for re-opening?"

It should be possible to revert the vote  to re-open the question.
E.g. 're-open' link can work as a toggle to undo the vote.

Related questions [Undo a reopen request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284239/undo-a-reopen-request) and [How do I un-nominate a re-open vote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302960/how-do-i-un-nominate-a-re-open-vote) ask is it possible to undo vote  to re-open the question. My feature request asks to implement this ability.

The current process of expiring a re-open vote after four days is not obvious, and may be too late, if your vote causes the question to re-open.

Comment: Editing auto-generated text seem to be a bit strange... I'd instead add comment and possibly in [SOVTC chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for assistance to re-close.

Comment: I don't see any reopen votes on that question.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I did it some time ago. Reopen votes are expired after 4 days, but it's not obvious for user.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov just a friendly FYI - that room is called SOCVR, not SOVTC :-)

Comment: This is probably a better fit for Meta.SE.